# css slider with radio buttons on smartphone

Tags: css, slider, user-experience

Can you tell me why I can see the radio buttons, which I used for my slider, on my smartphone? If I am swiping on the screen while the slider is moving, the picture pops up...
[Smartphone View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJgXl.png)

Furthermore I would like to edit my code for 100% ux, so please correct the code if you can! :)

website: [flmueller.de](https://flmueller.de)

CSS:

```
.slider-wrapper
{
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.slider
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;

    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1500ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform 1500ms, transform 1500ms;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.slide1
{
    background-image: url("/img/slider_01_s.jpg");
    left: 0%;
}

.slide2
{
    background-image: url("/img/slider_02_s.jpg");
    left: 100%;
}

.slide3
{
    background-image: url("/img/slider_03_s.jpg");
    left: 200%;
}

.slide4
{
    background-image: url("/img/slider_04_s.jpg");
    left: 300%;
}

.slide5
{
    background-image: url("/img/slider_05_s.jpg");
    left: 400%;
}

.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.slide-radio5:checked ~ .slider
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400%);
    transform: translateX(-400%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" />
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" />
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" />
    <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio5" />

    <div class="slider slide1">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>photography</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slide2">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>cinematography</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slide3">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>design</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slide4">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>code</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider slide5">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>love</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to hide them - I can't recreate on my device however just hiding them seems to be the best solution.

```
input[type="radio"] { visibility: hidden; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well, the radio buttons are not there anymore, but there is still the problem with the white background while the slider is active